# Cannot add two element on the same row in cell

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have this structure:

```html
<td class="sorting_1" tabindex="0">
    <div class="form-check" data-user-id="1">
       <label class="form-check-label">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value=""> 
           <span class="form-check-sign">
               <span class="check"></span>
           </span>
       </label>
   </div>
   <div class="photo">
       <img src=".././uploads/images/avatar/1.png">
   </div>
</td>
```

I would like add both checkbox and image on the same row but I get the image on another line, how can I fix that?

Comment: td determines the size based on its content. div on its parent. This is a loop that may lead to  unpredictable results. Are you using tables for layout?

Comment: Either use `display: flex;` (flexbox) on the parent or set both div to `display: inline-block;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display: inline-block`:

```html
<td class="sorting_1" tabindex="0">
    <div class="form-check" data-user-id="1" style="display:inline-block">
       <label class="form-check-label">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value=""> 
           <span class="form-check-sign">
               <span class="check"></span>
           </span>
       </label>
   </div>
   <div class="photo" style="display:inline-block">
       <img src=".././uploads/images/avatar/1.png">
   </div>
</td>
```

If you have a lot of these, you can make a CSS rule:

```css
.form-check, .photo {
display: inline-block
}
```

```html
<td class="sorting_1" tabindex="0">
    <div class="form-check" data-user-id="1">
       <label class="form-check-label">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value=""> 
           <span class="form-check-sign">
               <span class="check"></span>
           </span>
       </label>
   </div>
   <div class="photo">
       <img src=".././uploads/images/avatar/1.png">
   </div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

problem is because `div` is a block element and that goes to a new line by default if you replace it with span it should work

```html
<td class="sorting_1" tabindex="0">
    <span class="form-check" data-user-id="1">
       <label class="form-check-label">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value=""> 
           <span class="form-check-sign">
               <span class="check"></span>
           </span>
       </label>
   </span>
   <span class="photo">
       <img src=".././uploads/images/avatar/1.png">
   </span>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<td class="sorting_1" tabindex="0">
    <div class="form-check" data-user-id="1">
        <label class="form-check-label">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value=""> 
            <span class="form-check-sign">
                <span class="check"></span>
            </span>
        </label>
        <img src=".././uploads/images/avatar/1.png" class="photo">
    </div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

that is because the image element is inside "div", and browser consider div a [block element] as default, so you can: 
1- move img up below the span
2- change div.photo style (inline style or inside css file) to : .photo {display:inline-block}